# Deployed a fullstack web service on render, received localhost:3000 ECONNREFUSED error when going to website link

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, deployment, dotenv

When I click on my render link, this is what is shown:

```
{"message":"","name":"AggregateError","stack":"AggregateError
   at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)","config":
{"url":"http://localhost:3000/api/users","method":"get","headers":
{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","User-
Agent":"axios/0.21.4"},"transformRequest":\[null],"transformResponse":[null],
"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-
XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"transitional":
{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false}},"code":"ECONNREFUSED"}
```

A kind fellow suggested that it may be a client side issue, as I probably hardcoded localhost:3000 as my deployed URL.

```
dotenv.config({
  path: 'config.env'
});
const PORT = 3000;

// parse request to body-parser
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// load routers
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is the section of my server.js file that handles connecting.
The link that I'm trying to host my website on is https://ultideploy.onrender.com

I know I have to update my deployed URLs since I've hardcoded it to localhost, but I have no idea how to. Would appreciate any advice or help.

This is my first time deploying so I'm still learning how to deploy a website.
Thank you!

I've tried doing `path: 'https://ultideploy.onrender.com'` but the build failed with this error  `` MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string. ``